# Present GKGameCenterViewController in a Cocos2d 3 project

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I'm trying to make a leaderboard for a game I created using SpriteBuilder. I have the following code.

```
if (gameCenterController != nil)
{
    gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
    gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
    UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
    [vc presentViewController: gameCenterController animated: YES completion:nil];
}
```

However, on the UIViewController *vc line, I keep getting the following error, "Property 'view' not found on object of type 'MainScene *'.

I have been searching for hours, does anyone know of a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

*MainScene* does not have a `view` property because it isn't a `UIViewController`.
There is only one `UIViewController` in a Cocos2d application and that is the `CCDirector`.

If you want to present a view controller you need to present it from the `CCDirector`:

```
 [[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually answered my own question! :D

```
UIViewController *vc = [[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] window] rootViewController];
```

Comment: actually this can be condensed to: [CCDirector sharedDirector] (CCDirector is cocos2d's UIViewController)